# jQuery Automatic Click Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-mvc

I have a telerik MVC Grid that is group by Shipping Priority. When the column is drag onto the grouping area, it is grouping and sorting ascending. I'd like to switch it so that it is sorting descending. I tried to using the jQuery function below to click on the button, but it is not fire. What am I missing here?

```
$(function () {
        var item = $("#Shipping tbody > .t-grouping-header > .t-grouping-indicator");
          alert(item) //Says that is an object. I also made sure that it has a click property by iterating through item
          $(item).click(function() {
            alert('you click me');
            item.click();
        });
    });
    });
```

Updated on 02/07/2014 @12:42 PM

[Here is the link where I describe the grid that I am using.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557147/reordering-telerik-column-after-grouping)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that using

```
$(item).trigger("click");
```

Works rather well for me. It also calls one less function than `.click()`

Comment: Thank RUJordon, I changed it but it did not appear to make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change:

```
item.click();
```

to:

```
$(item).click();
```

Btw, you've redundant closing `});` in your code as well.

Comment: Thank Felix. I tried item.click too and it still did not do anything.

Comment: I still could not get the grid to sort if the user were to click on sort. The customer agreed that they could simply click on sort button again to get the data to sort properly. It's a bummer that I could not get to work properly, but I am moving on.

Comment: The .trigger does click on the item; I had several alerts that were fired when using .trigger(). However, the sorting still did not work.